# Failed to read logs from event logs with C# in Azure Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, event-log, windows-server-2012-r2

I created Windows Server 2012 R2 machine in Azure and I try to create simple c# application to read logs from event logs.

I am using the `EventLog`, `EventLogQuery`, `EventLogReader` classes to read the logs.

I test the code in a private virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 (in my PC) and its worked great, I was able to read the logs locally and from remote.

When I run my code in Azure, I get EventLogException with the message:

> "The RPC server is unavailable"

I try to enable some firewall rules & start some services but it didn't help.

Do anyone know the issue ? Do you have any other solution to read the event logs ?

I see some people that read the logs with PowerShell but I prefer to do it with pure c#

Thanks.

Comment: This is unlikely an Azure issue - more likely to just be a permissions issue on Server 2012.

Comment: I am administrator in my azure machine, so I don't think its a permissions problem. Do you have any suggestions how to check if it really a permission issue ?